# Script to change permission on content, and move files to other folder

Tags: server, permissions, scripts

I have a program that downloads some files. I want those files to automatically change permissions to 755, and get moved to another folder on my system. I want this to autorun every hour.

Is this possible? I'm not good at scripting, but I'm pretty good in terminal. My system is an Ubuntu server 12.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can.

The script might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set permissions
chmod 755 /home/user/Downloads/*

# Move files
mv /home/user/Downloads/* "/home/user/New Location/"
```

Save this as something like `/home/user/download-script.sh` and make sure to run `chmod u+x /home/user/download-script.sh` so it can be executed.

To have this executed periodically you could use cron. Enter `crontab -e` and create an entry like this:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/download-script.sh
```

This would lead to the script being executed every hour exactly (so, say 1:00 am, 2:00 am, etc.).

You can expand on this of course. Depending on whether there might be folders in you `Downloads` directory, you might want to add `-R` to the `chmod`-command to make changes recurse into those directories for example. Hope this helps :).

Note: You might want to be careful about when you use `755` as far as permissions go! Does *everybody* really need to execute those files? Maybe something like `764` is enough already.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for! Can I make this to run without login in? Sometimes the power goes out, and I have the people I live with starting the server again. Will this run after a boot? :)

About the permissions. I took 755 like an example, I think 764 would be better.

I understand all of the script, but the crontab "0 * * * * /home/user/download-script.sh" wil this make it run as my user, or root?

Comment: Yes, this will run even if you don't log in! If you run `crontab -e` with your regular user's account, the script will be executed as that user, too. if you do `sudo crontab -e` the script will execute with `root`'s permissions. Also, if this answer solved your question, feel free to mark it as such :).